# Прошивка маршрутизатора

Tags: маршрутизатор

Тупит маршрутизатор при первом включении компьютера, нужно раз 10 перезагрузить, так может через мин 15 подключится. Звонил в тех.поддержку, сказали что у них все отлично. Хочу прошить но не знаю какую прошивку выбрать. Маршрутизатор DSL-2500U, **H/W Ver:C1, F/WVer:TT_1.01**. [Вот что говорят на их сайте.](http://dlink.ru/ru/faq/156/938.html)

Пробовал ту которая для ревизии: **С1** и типа линии: **Annex A**, но при обновлении говорит мол не подходит F/W там же вроде как **F/W Ver:RU_** , а у меня **F/W Ver:TT_1.01**, где такую достать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это кастомизированная прошивка для оператора Таттелеком. Она базируется на версии RU_1.01, но с уже содержит настройки WAN. Если есть необходимость, то можно обновиться до последней версии. (обратите внимание на строку H/W Ver.: на стикере модема, в зависимости от ревизии Dx или Сx выберите прошивку). Для DSL-2500U/BRU/D: RU_1.52 Для DSL-2500U/BRU/C: RU_1.31

Для обновления прошивки воспользуйтесь crash-mode.